# <script> tag inside a tab

Tags: html

I am injecting some html as a tab and was wondering, do I need to put the relevant script tags inside the html I am injecting, or inside the main html.

For example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- would my tab specific script go here?-->
    </head>

    <!--html being injected as a tab-->
    <div>
       <!--got from an external html file-->
       <html>
           <head>
               <!-- or here?--> 
           </head>
       </hmtl>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends on what the script does.

Comment: it is jquery, to initialize a datepicker object

Comment: inside the tab html, I have 
    <script>
        $("datepicker").datepicker();
    </script>

Answer (score -1):

If it's a small script, I would put it in the main document. If you need to load the JS after your main document because it's big and rarely used, you can try jQuery.getScript().

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/